# I wanna set minlength＆maxlength in template of input tag

Tags: python, html, django

I wrote in index.html

```html
    <div class="heading col-lg-6 col-md-12">                     
            <h2>New account registration</h2>
        
            <form class="form-horizontal" action="regist_save/" method="POST">                     
              <div class="form-group-lg">                     
                <label for="id_username">username</label>
                                     {{ regist_form.username }}                     
              </div>                                          
              <div class="form-group-lg">                     
                <label for="id_email">email</label>
                                      {{ regist_form.email }}
              </div>   
              <div class="form-group-lg">                     
                <label for="id_password">password</label>                     
                 {{ regist_form.password1 }}                     
              </div>                                          
              <div class="form-group-lg">
                <label for="id_password">password（conformation）</label>                     
                 {{ regist_form.password2 }}
                 <p class="help-block">{{ regist_form.password2.help_text }}</p>                     
              </div>                                          
              <div class="form-group-lg">
                <div class="col-xs-offset-2">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">SUBMIT</button>                     
                <input name="next" type="hidden"/>                     
                </div>
              </div>
              {% csrf_token %}                     
            </form>                     
    </div>
```

I wanna set minlength＆maxlength in template of username&password input tag.If i wrote in html stye,it is

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" action="regist_save/" method="POST">                     
              <div class="form-group-lg">                     
                <label for="id_username">username</label>
                      <input id="id_username" name="username" type="text" value="" minlength="5" maxlength="12" placeholder="username" class="form-control">               
              </div>                                          
              <div class="form-group-lg">                     
                <label for="id_email">email</label>
                                      {{ regist_form.email }}
              </div>   
              <div class="form-group-lg">                     
                <label for="id_password">password</label>                     
                 <input id="id_password1" name="password1" type="password1" value="" minlength="8" maxlength="12" placeholder="password1" class="form-control">  
              </div>                                          
              <div class="form-group-lg">
                <label for="id_password">password（conformation）</label>                     
                 <input id="id_password2" name="password2" type="password2" value="" minlength="8" maxlength="12" placeholder="password2" class="form-control">  
                 <p class="help-block">{{ regist_form.password2.help_text }}</p>                     
              </div>                                          
              <div class="form-group-lg">
                <div class="col-xs-offset-2">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">SUBMIT</button>                     
                <input name="next" type="hidden"/>                     
                </div>
              </div>
              {% csrf_token %}                     
            </form>
```

in forms.py

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email','password1','password1',)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RegisterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['email'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
```

in views.py

```
@require_POST
def regist_save(request):
    regist_form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
    if regist_form.is_valid():
        user = regist_form.save(commit=False)
        password = regist_form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        login(request, user)
        context = {
            'user': request.user,
        }
        return redirect('detail')

    context = {
        'regist_form': regist_form,
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/regist.html', context)
```

I wanna set username minlength="5" &maxlength="12" and password minlength="8" & maxlength="12".I wanna write it in template,although I searched the way in Google but i cannot find it.I think i can do it by template but do i misunderstand it?Can't i do it in template?

Comment: to set minlength and maxlength you have to set these attributes with values and validation will work accordingly

Answer (score 0):

you can set **maxlength** and **minlength** by using these attributes with your desired limit and validation will work accordingly

[Working example on W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_maxlength)

Comment: thx ur comments.I cannot understand how I should combine Django template&input tag.How should I do it?

Comment: now this is your rite Question. post same question.